# Getting a set of values from a resource file in C#

Tags: c#, internationalization

I am storing a set of values in a resource file (resx) and have namespaced the values like so:

```
Form.Option.Value1 | Car 
Form.Option.Value2 | Lorry
Form.Option.Value3 | Bus
Form.Option.Value4 | Train
```

If there a way with the System.Resources.ResourceManager class to retrieve all these values in one go. I am look for a sort of get by prefix method:

```
ResourceManager manager ...
IEnumerable<string> values = manager.GetStringsByPrefix("Form.Option");
```

The reason for doing this is that we have a form with a dropdown where the values may need to change depending on the culture.

Also is it possible to get back the string values as key value pairs so I can get the name of the resource and its value, e.g.:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> values = manager.GetPairWithPrefix("Form.Options")
```

Comment: `Form.Option` sounds very much like something that should be in a Config file, not in a Resource file.

Comment: A Config file won't automatically do internationalization.

Comment: Right, on second read it makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enumerate all strings for a specific language in the ResourceManager, using the [GetResourceSet method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourceset.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you use the localization feature built into Visual Studio / .NET Framework to localize your forms (including combo box lists) it generates code like this:

Found in Form1.de.resx:

```
<data name="comboBox1.Items" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Auto</value>
</data>
<data name="comboBox1.Items1" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Bahn</value>
</data>
```

Found in Form1.resx:

```
<data name="comboBox1.Items" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Car</value>
</data>
<data name="comboBox1.Items1" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Train</value>
</data>
```

And it loads them like this (found in Form1.Designer.cs in Initializecomponent):

```
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));

resources.ApplyResources(this.comboBox1, "comboBox1");
this.comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
   resources.GetString("comboBox1.Items"),
   resources.GetString("comboBox1.Items1")});
this.comboBox1.Name = "comboBox1";
```

It may not be exactly the answer you asked for, but being the solution that the creators of .NET came up with to the exact same problem, I suspect it would be of interest.

If you want to use the .NET/VS-native localization, just set the Language property of the form and then update all the strings via the IDE.  When you switch back to (Default) your original strings will be restored.  Both languages will be remembered in language-specific resx files.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be along the lines of what I want but I am doing this with MVC3.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably reconsider the format. Like

```
 Form.Option.Value = Car;Lorry;Bus;...
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response, I solved this by sub-classing the ResourceManager and adding a new  method:

```
public class ResourceManager : System.Resources.ResourceManager
{
    public ResourceManager(Type resourceSource)
        : base(resourceSource)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetStringsByPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        return GetStringsByPrefix(prefix, null);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> GetStringsByPrefix(string prefix, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (prefix == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("prefix");
        if (culture == null)
            culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
        var resourceSet = this.InternalGetResourceSet(culture, true, true);

        IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = resourceSet.GetEnumerator();
        List<string> results = new List<string>();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            string key = (string)enumerator.Key;


            if (key.StartsWith(prefix))
            {
                results.Add((string)enumerator.Value);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that all resources are strings, and is not thread safe since it's using InternalGetResourceSet.

You could replace the List and the while loop with this to take the string part into account:
`return from DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet
                   where entry.Value is string
                         && ((string) entry.Key).StartsWith(prefix)
                   select (string) entry.Value;`

Answer (score 0):

Although the IDE for editing resx files doesn't support it, you can add string arrays (and I suspect any serializable class) to an resx file:

```
string outPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
outPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(outPath, "MyResources.resx");
using (System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter rw = new System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter(outPath))
{
   rw.AddResource("ComboBox1Values", new string[] { "Car", "Train" });
   rw.Generate();
   rw.Close();
}
```

In the output file you'll see something like:

```
<data name="ComboBox1Values" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
  <value>AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAARAQAAAAIAAAAGAgAAAANDYXIGAwAAAAVUcmFpbgs=</value>
</data>
```